# How do I make an ASP.NET TreeView not visible using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'd like to click a node in my ASP.NET TreeView and make `visible=false;`. How do I do that in JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a NagivateUrl equal to a Javascript function in the TreeView node to hide the button.

```
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" >
        <Nodes>
            <asp:TreeNode Text="" Value="" NavigateUrl="javascript:HideButton();"></asp:TreeNode>
        </Nodes>
    </asp:TreeView>

 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function HideButton() {
        document.getElementById('<%=Button1.ClientID %>').style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: then how to add the navigate url for tree nodes... like (NavigateUrl="~/home.aspx")?

Comment: Good Question; on click of node, if you want to hide the button then why you want to go on other page ? If you really want to go another page, you can put Window.Location in javascript function after hiding the button.

Comment: yes, i am using frames here, left frame and right frame. in left im having hyperlink,button and below is treeview menu, while clicking tree nodes i have to hide the button in same frame as well as navigate to corresponding page in right frame....

Comment: well, if you are using Freme, then you have to use Target property of node.

Comment: this is my sample node '<asp:TreeNode Text="Welcome" Value="New Node" NavigateUrl="~/home.aspx" Target="main" >'...

Comment: if u give like this '<asp:TreeNode Text="Welcome" Value="New Node" NavigateUrl="javascript:HideButton();" Target="main" >'  it wont work...

Comment: I don't know your exact scanrio and what you want to achieve. Upon provided your sample TreeNode, I suggest you to hide your button on server side, you can use AJAX something. I have not seen any other property that we can call javascript function instead Navigate URL.

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar  after clicking page will be postback.

Comment: @Govind; If you try my solution at your end; there will be no postback at all.

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar : your sample 100% correct but he used url so on click page will be postback so he has to manage at server or other solution.

Comment: yes, I already suggest him, if he have url in his Navigate URL property. If you read my above comments

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
document.getElementById("buttonId").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

or

```
document.getElementById("buttonId").style.display = "none";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about calling *JavaScript* functions from codebehind, use [Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript](http://www.devcurry.com/2009/01/execute-javascript-function-from-aspnet.html) .

Comment: i am using **treeview,hyperlink and button** in a page, if clicked hyperlink that button should be visible, if clicked any node parent node or chiled node in treeview that button should be invisible.